# Why is the date returned as "0001-01-01" when calling a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, soap

I have a very peculiar problem.

I have this code:

```
DT_PMNotificationRequestRecords request = new DT_PMNotificationRequestRecords();
request.NOTIF_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(txtNotifData.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
request.REQ_START = DateTime.ParseExact(txtReqStart.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now both `Notif_DATE` and `REQ_START` have proper date values.

But when the request object is passed to the web service that I have written using the same class as an object in array.

```
requestRecords = new DT_PMNotificationRequestRecords[]{request, request2};

Notif = new Notifications.SI_PMNotification_Out_SyncResponseSoapClient(bindingHttp, endPointHttp);

Notif.SI_PMNotification_Out_Sync(requestRecords);
```

Web service:

```
public DT_PMNotificationResponseRecords[] SI_PMNotification_Out_Sync(DT_PMNotificationRequestRecords[] request)
{
    try
    {
```

Here in the request object the `REQ_Start` date is returned as "0001-01-01" but `notif_date` is correct, e.g. `10-10-2019`.

In class the fields are defined like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date", Order=6)]
public System.DateTime NOTIF_DATE 
{
    get { return this.nOTIF_DATEField; }
    set { 
           this.nOTIF_DATEField = value;
           this.RaisePropertyChanged("NOTIF_DATE");
        }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date", Order=10)]
public System.DateTime REQ_START 
{
    get { return this.rEQ_STARTField; }
    set {
            this.rEQ_STARTField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("REQ_START");
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `txtNotifData.Text`?

Comment: @mjwills: 13-10-2019

Comment: You are trying to parse that string as `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format. Does your string match that format (with a four digit year at the start of the string)?

Comment: ok I have matched the string. Now I am passing in the format yyyy-MM-dd i.e. 2019-10-13 and for notifData it saves but for REQ_START the same date is converted to 0001-01-01. Why? And that after getting received as a variable in the service.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `txtReqStart.Text` (check in the `Immediate Window`)?

Comment: 13/10/2019 00:00:00

Comment: but while getting assigned to the variable it's 2019-10-13

Comment: 13/10/2019 00:00:00 is the one shown in immediate window but the 2019-10-13 is the one shown while getting assigned to the variable while debugging.

Comment: hi, I checked in the immediate window before calling the service. I typed request.REQ_START and it returned 13/10/2019 00:00:00. 

Then after calling the webservice, I went to webservice and checked in immediate window by typing request.REQ_START 01/01/0001 00:00:00.

Comment: `but while getting assigned to the variable it's 2019-10-13` Please explain how you saw that.

Comment: @mjwills: while debugging when it reached that line where the REQ_Start was getting the value assigned, it was 2019-10-13.